# Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays (LSTM, TensorFlow)

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, input, lstm

i've been trying to debug said error for a while now, sadly with no luck whatsoever. I want to train an LSTM network using a collection of arrays of floats, with shape `(time_steps, 63)`, where time_steps is not a fixed value, i.e. there are arrays with shape (39, 63), (28, 63) and so on. As LSTM networks require a 3D input, I then reshaped each of those arrays in a `(1, time_steps, 63)` shape, `[(samples, time_steps, features)]`, and set the network's input_shape parameter as `input_shape=(None, 63)`.
The x_train length is currently equal to 816, same thing for the y_train array, so I have no idea why i'm getting said error.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
def load_dataset(self):
   
    x_train = [] # samples
    y_train = [] # labels
    gesture_number = len(next(os.walk('training_data'))[1])
    for index in range(0, gesture_number):
        # print("Label: " + str(index))
        gesture_path = 'training_data/gesture_' + str(index) + "/"
        for file_name in os.scandir(gesture_path):
            if file_name.is_file():
                joints = self.get_data_from_file(file_name.path)
                reshaped_joints = np.asarray(joints, dtype=object).reshape(1, len(joints), 63)
                x_train.append(reshaped_joints)
                y_train.append(index)
    return x_train, y_train

def create_model(self, x_train, y_train):
    # callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)
    network_model = Sequential([
        LSTM(units=128, input_shape=(None, 63), activation='relu'),
        Dense(units=16, activation='softmax')
    ])
    network_model.summary()

    network_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                          metrics=['accuracy'])

    network_model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train,
                      batch_size=1,
                      epochs=10,
                      shuffle=True,
                      verbose=2)

    network_model.save(network_path)

def create_network(self):
        x_train, y_train = op.load_dataset()
        # shuffle(x_train, y_train)
        self.create_model(x_train, y_train)
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vince/Documents/Projects/Borsa/gesture-recognition-demo/setup/NetworkModule.py", line 5, in <module>
    nt.manage_network()
  File "/Users/vince/Documents/Projects/Borsa/gesture-recognition-demo/setup/NetworkSetup.py", line 66, in manage_network
    self.create_network()
  File "/Users/vince/Documents/Projects/Borsa/gesture-recognition-demo/setup/NetworkSetup.py", line 59, in create_network
    self.create_model(x_train, y_train)
  File "/Users/vince/Documents/Projects/Borsa/gesture-recognition-demo/setup/NetworkSetup.py", line 49, in create_model
    verbose=2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 816, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays_v1.py", line 632, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 2344, in _standardize_user_data
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 2446, in _standardize_tensors
    training_utils_v1.check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils_v1.py", line 774, in check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 816 target samples.
```

Comment: Is the variable `joints` in the loop of variable time steps length?

Comment: joints is made of n arrays with 63 values each, where n is equal to the rows of the file being read, so n (timesteps) x 63 values

Comment: Is y_train of dimension (samples x 16)? it should be according to the last layer of the model.

Comment: I did not see that you use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, so the shape of y_tain is (samples,)

Comment: y_train is made of 816 samples, basically 816 labels, and when I go ahead and print its shape I do get (816,) indeed :)

Comment: ok the error says _Found 1 input samples and 816 target samples_. I tried to run your code on some dummy data and I have an error if I don't cast y_train from list to numpy array.

Comment: the error sounds kinda weird to me as if I print the lengths right before calling model.fit I do get 816 for both.. It happens if I try to convert said list to a numpy array, via y=np.asarray(y_train), too :/

Comment: Can you display the shape of x_train?

Comment: I cannot as its shape varies according to the timesteps, I can only print its length.
We can assume it's something like (816, timesteps, 63)

Comment: and the shape of the first x_train sample ?

Comment: yup, I can print it for each of the samples.. in this case It would be (1, 39, 63)

Comment: shouldn't the shape of sample 0 be (39, 63)?

Comment: it is so in the for loop, then it gets reshaped in order to be sent to the network as a 3D input, going from (39, 63) to (1, 39, 63)

Comment: yes but you said that it is a list of numpy arrays,
what I suggest: try to make x_train a 3D numpy array, either by cropping the number of steps of the _joints_ to the minimum or by padding with zeros. Just to test if this is the source of the problem

Comment: I kinda did something like that, I read 10 rows from each file in order to have an (816, 10, 63)-shaped x_train array, but the error comes up in that case too :/

Comment: last try: I see tensorflow/python/keras/engine/ **training_v1.py** in the error message, which version of tensorflow and keras are you using?

Comment: Hold on I just realised something: I re-did the 10 rows operation, without reshaping, in order to get an (816, 10, 63)-shaped x_train array, then fed that very array to the network by using [x_train] and [y_train] (self.create_model([x_train], [y_train]) and the training started correctly!

Also I'm using tensorflow 2.5.0, a modified wheel made to be able to run on Apple's M1 chip as I'm using the MediaPipe Framework as a base, which doesn't run on M1 natively

Comment: Great! Now you can pre-process using zero padding to get a 3D shaped x_train and use masking to handle variable time steps [Masking and padding with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding)

Comment: Will take a look to that! :) Thank you so much!